# How to add or include relation ship data in list EFO core Mock

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, foreign-keys

How to add one to many relationship data in a mock list for testing purpose

like
context.Table.Include(e => e.subtable)

how to do this in list collection

Answer (score -1):

This is Simple Just use User Join in (List) instated of include in (context) This link will help you

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins